# How to write logic inside Nest js Middleware and Guard

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to make Multiple role Access Project Where I have to allow user according to their roles , so for this I have to create multiple Middleware & Guard according to Roles but there is no documentation how to get current login user details inside Nest Middleware and also how to get current login user details from jsonWebToken inside Nest Guard & Middleware,

I have Users collection schema is Like that

```
UsersCollectionSchema: {
  name: '',
  email:'',
  password:'',
  roles: [ admin, editor]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user has been authenticated, i suggest you to attach the user object to the request, it’s the common way, in order to have access to the user inside the middleware through the request and inside the guard through the request that you can get from the executionContext

Here is an example https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/01-cats-app/src/common/guards/roles.guard.ts

Comment: Thank you for your reply Adrien De Peretti , after authenticated is it good practice that I had to send whole use request as payload in every API call? Instead of sending user object I am sending Authenticated user token in a header so in middleware I could read token and find it roles using mongoQuery How is that Solution ??

Comment: Is it yes that way on each api call you will reduce the fetch count of the resource, this is a performance gain as well.